# </form> being automattically added to my HTML in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that I would like the following:

```
a <form action POST>

select List1 - with onchange set populate list 2

select List2  populated using JavaScript <div id="secondList"></div>

with an <input type="submit" value="Assign">

close the </form>
```

The second populates list fine. The problem seems to be (when checked in FireBug) that the /form tag is moved for some reason so that the order appears like this:

```
<form action POST>  </form>

select list 1 - correct

list 2 - correctly populated

the <input type="submit" value="Assign">
```

Why does this happen and how can get around this problem?

**HTML CODE**

```
<tr>
<form action="webiste/assignToDepartment.php" method="post">
<td>
<select selected="All" name="firstItem" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value)">
<option value="item1">item1</option>  
<option value="item2">item2</option>  
<option value="item3">item3</option>  
</select>
</td>

<td>
<div id="secondList"></div>
</td>  

<td>
<input type="submit" value="Assign">
</td>

</form>

</tr>
```

Comment: you have a div inside a select? Please try to validate first your markup

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan a div inside a select???? where?? or i am blind or you are

Comment: Remember to close the input tag. Running the page thru a validator (http://validator.w3.org/) is a good way to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: @PauloRoberto - It's in the first and second code blocks in the question.

Comment: tr element is followed by td and then inside the td form can come ,invalid markup

Comment: @nnnnnn but.... the first blocks are not examples? at my understanding they are examples and the last block its the real code

Comment: @AlexK. `<input>` tags dont really need to be closed.

Comment: Time to learn some HTML basics.

Comment: @PauloRoberto - OP says the first block is the desired output, so... The question disagrees with itself. The whole thing could be solved with an html validator...

Comment: wow, this question is really confusing me @nnnnnn agreed

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - the initial lines were not code as such and thereto keep it simple (I thought). Edited to make it easier to read (I hope).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<form>` element has to be placed inside the `<td>` item. `<td>` and `<th>` are the only valid children of `<tr>`. Alternatively, since your form spans several columns, you'll need to wrap the form around the containing `<table>`, something like:

```
<form>
    <table>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Brilliant - sounds daft but been trying so many different things for days!! Life saver.

Comment: Glad I could help, Richard.

Answer (score 2):

your form element should be placed inside the  tag or around the entire table

Answer (score 1):

make your html proper like this

```
   <form action="webiste/assignToDepartment.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>

          <td>
           <select selected="All" name="firstItem" onchange="checkTeacherList(this.value)">
             <option value="item1">item1</option>  
             <option value="item2">item2</option>  
             <option value="item3">item3</option>  
            </select>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div id="secondList"></div>
          </td>  

          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Assign">
         </td>

      </tr>

    </table>   
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Firebug's HTML pane does not show the raw HTML sent by the server. Instead, it shows a nice tree graph with the structure of the document and that tree is built with the memory representation of the document nodes. It's not possible to build an invalid tree, thus invalid HTML needs to be fixed or ignored.

If you pass your HTML through the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) (you might need to check the "Validate HTML fragment" option if you don't provide the complete document) you'll see it reports several errors about the document structure:

- document type does not allow element "XXXX" here
- end tag for "XXXX" which is not finished

You need to fix that to ensure proper rendering and, as a consequence, proper scripting.

P.S. While there're normally exact specs on how to process valid HTML, invalid HTML is often left to the browser's discretion. That's a good reason to avoid invalid tags: there can be drastic differences in the way they're rendered by different browsers.